# GCP Autoscaler Instance Group Error: service account issue

Tags: google-cloud-platform

I'm trying to create an instance group for autoscaling and after creation, there is this red icon with an exclamation point next to the instance group name, telling me the the service account xxx (this is the efault service account actually) is not associated with the project.

I don't get it, and I don't see how to fix this.

Does anybody know this one ?

[image: screenshot of instance group screen]

Answer (score 0):

It seems that the [Google APIs Service Account](https://cloud.google.com/compute/docs/access/service-accounts#google_apis_service_account) was missing permissions in your project.

The service account should be added to the project as part of activation of compute APIs. But it can be also manually deleted/added to your project.

The easiest procedure to enable it in your project (so grant Managed Instance Group permission to edit your instances) is to execute following script:

```
PROJECT_NAME=your-project-name

PROJECT_ID=`gcloud projects describe $PROJECT_NAME --format 'value(projectNumber)'`
gcloud projects add-iam-policy-binding ${PROJECT_NAME}  --member=serviceAccount:${PROJECT_ID}@cloudservices.gserviceaccount.com --role=roles/editor
```

Alternatively you can configure it on IAM page of your project in the developer console.